# WPF DataGrid Vertical Scroll Bar Issues with Dynamically Loaded Item Source

Tags: c#, wpf

The issue: Cannot get the Vertical Scroll bar for the DataGrid to appear unless I set a static height on the grid. I know similar questions have been asked before, however unlike other questions my example is a lot more simple with no Grid Columns. The DataGrid is simply inside a StackPanel inside the  control. That's it, and no combination of Auto, "*", etc works except setting a static Height.

Is this simply a lacking feature in WPF framework that it a Observable Collection on the ViewModel bound to a grid, will not notify the View when items are added to the VM Collection? Do I have to code a custom property and bind the DataGrid Height to that?

Here is my XMAL:

```
<Window x:Class="Monster.Configure"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Monster.ViewModels"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Monster"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Configure" Width="1200">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:ViewModelMain/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="5">

            <Button Name="button_Refresh" Content="Save / Refresh" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Width="100"
                    Click="button_Refresh_Click"></Button>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--Buttons and other junk here-->
            </StackPanel>
            <Label></Label>

                <DataGrid Name="dataGrid_PendingCreation" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding URLsForGrid}" 
                        Loaded="dataGrid_PendingCreation_Loaded"
                        CellEditEnding="dataGrid_PendingCreation_CellEditEnding"
                        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility ="Auto"
                        Width="Auto" Height="Auto">

                    <DataGrid.Columns>

                    <!--Columns and junk here-->

                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>


        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see, the user is allowed to add new rows. When doing so, a Vertical Scroll Bar never shows up unless a Static Height is set in the DataGrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DataGrid` is wrapped inside a `StackPanel` (with vertical orientation). A vertically oriented `StackPanel` always gives seemingly infinite available height to its children. Since your `DataGrid`'s `Height` property is set to `Auto`, it will grow as large as it can; it will never show a vertical scrollbar, because this is done only if the `DataGrid`'s available height (determined by the parent) is less than the actually needed height.

The solution is not to use a `StackPanel` here. Instead, use a `Grid` or a `DockPanel`.
I usually prefer the latter, if all I want to achieve is vertical or horizontal stacking of the children and have one child stretch as wide as possible; here is how it would be done:

```
<Window>
    ...
    <Grid>
        ...
        <DockPanel Margin="5">
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="button_Refresh" ... />
            <StackPanel  DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--Buttons and other junk here-->
            </StackPanel>
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Label>
            <DataGrid Name="dataGrid_PendingCreation" ... />
        </DockPanel>
        ...
    </Grid>
    ...
</Window>
```

Make sure that `DataGrid` is the last child in the DockPanel and that it has no `DockPanel.Dock` property. This ensures that the `DataGrid` will be given the available height and width that remains after placing all other controls.